# Laravel - How to resolve: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object when value is NULL

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8 project, when I submitted the code below:

```
public function publish_all_posts(){
    $userCompany = Auth::user()->company_id;
    $userEmployee = Auth::user()->employee_id;    
    $userId = Auth::user()->id;
    $userEmail = Auth::user()->email;
    $userCode = Auth::user()->employee_code;
    $userFirstName = Auth::user()->first_name;
    $userLastName = Auth::user()->last_name;   

    $identities = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('id')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    $reviewperiods = DB::table('appraisal_identity')->select('appraisal_name')->where('company_id', $userCompany)->where('is_current', 1)->first();
    $reviewperiod = $reviewperiods->appraisal_name;


    $linemanager = DB::table('hr_employees')->where('id', $userEmployee)->first();

    $linemanageruserid = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('line_manager_id')->where('line_manager_id', $linemanager->line_manager_id)->first();
    $linemanageruserids = DB::table('hr_employees')->where('id', $linemanageruserid->line_manager_id)->first();
    $linemanageremails = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('email')->where('id', $linemanageruserids->id)->first();

    $linemanageremail = $linemanageremails->email;

    if ($unapproved_count > 3){
    $unapproved_post = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_published',0)
            ->update([
                'is_published' => 1,
                'is_approved' => 1

                ]);

    $unapproved_post = AppraisalGoal::where('employee_id', $userEmployee)->where('appraisal_identity_id', $identities->id)->where('is_published',1)->first();


        Session::flash('success', 'Goals Published successfully');
        return redirect()->back();
    }else{
        Session::flash('info', 'You cannot proceed. Kindly Set all Goals before you publish!');
        return redirect()->back();
    } 
}
```

I got this error:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

and this line of code was highlighted:

```
$linemanageremails = DB::table('hr_employees')
    ->select('email')
    ->where('id', $linemanageruserids->id)
    ->first();
```

I found out that the error came because: $linemanageruserids is NULL

How do I resolve it?

Comment: is `$linemanageremails` being null expected? i dont think you need the code to work if it null. you should put an `if` and return generic error message if it null instead of trying to provide non-existent information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `$linemanageruserids` is returning null , which you can check conditionally and return the proper response.

```
if($linemanageruserids)
        $linemanageremails = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('email')->where('id', $linemanageruserids->id)->first();
```

Also you can check the count of the returned object by casting it to array and getting the count.

```
    if(count((array)$linemanageruserids))
        $linemanageremails = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('email')->where('id', $linemanageruserids->id)->first();
```